Encoding P-256 EC Key to JWK in Zig
I'm building an ACME client in Zig and I'm currently stuck on encoding a JWK (JSON Web Key) for an EC key. Specifically, I'm having trouble encoding the P-256 (ECDSA) key to a JWK format. Here’s the part of my code that I'm trying to fix:
pub fn jwkEncodeP256() ![]const u8 {
    const p = std.crypto.sign.ecdsa.EcdsaP256Sha256.KeyPair.create(null);
    const x = p.x.toBytes(.big);
    const y = p.y.toBytes(.big);

    var buf: [1024]u8 = undefined;

    const x_encoded = try encodeBase64url(x);
    const y_encoded = try encodeBase64url(y);

    const jws = try std.fmt.bufPrint(
        &buf,
        "{{\"crv\":\"P-256\",\"kty\":\"EC\",\"x\":\"{s}\",\"y\":\"{s}\"}}",
        .{ x_encoded, y_encoded },
    );
    return jws;
}

Could anyone help me out with generate correct x and y and encode them ??
I want to make jwk encode just like in golang
func jwkEncode(pub crypto.PublicKey) (string, error) {
    switch pub := pub.(type) {
    case *rsa.PublicKey:
        // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-6.3.1
        n := pub.N
        e := big.NewInt(int64(pub.E))
        // Field order is important.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7638#section-3.3 for details.
        return fmt.Sprintf({"e":"%s","kty":"RSA","n":"%s"},
            base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(e.Bytes()),
            base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(n.Bytes()),
        ), nil
    case *ecdsa.PublicKey:
        // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-6.2.1
        p := pub.Curve.Params()
        n := p.BitSize / 8
        if p.BitSize%8 != 0 {
            n++
        }
        x := pub.X.Bytes()
        if n > len(x) {
            x = append(make([]byte, n-len(x)), x...)
        }
        y := pub.Y.Bytes()
        if n > len(y) {
            y = append(make([]byte, n-len(y)), y...)
        }
        // Field order is important.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7638#section-3.3 for details.
        return fmt.Sprintf({"crv":"%s","kty":"EC","x":"%s","y":"%s"},
            p.Name,
            base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(x),
            base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(y),
        ), nil
    }
    return "", errUnsupportedKey
}
``


Your function, jwkEncodeP256 returns a pointer into the buf variable (a slice is a pointer albeit with some augmentation). The lifetime of buf is the same as the function. So, upon return, the memory object pointed to by jws no longer exists. Some languages, go I think, will determine if the value escapes the enclosing function and automatically allocate it from the heap. Zig does not do that as it goes against the explicitness that is central to Zig. You must design where you want the memory for your formatted string to live that has a lifetime longer than the function that generates the value. You may allocate it using an Allocator or put it in a container variable, but it must be some place other than the stack of the encoding function. This is a common mistake which you will easily see yourself when your "Zig think" has developed more.
